# Rails 3 Disable model not delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have several models that I want the user to "disable" it vs destroying it.  These models have a disable boolean.  trying to make this work.

currently in application_controller.rb

helper_method :disable

```
def disable(model)
 @model = "#{model}".find(params[:id])
 @model.update_attribute(:disable => true)
 flash[:notice] = "Successfully disabled #{model}."
 redirect_to company_ + "#{model}".pluralized + _url(current_company)
end
```

Do I have to create a new path in routes for each one I want to use this function?
Would be ideal, if I can do something similar like the destroy method.

Answer (score 6):

I would probably extend ActiveRecord with a disable method so that you can call @model.disable() just like you would @model.destroy(). That way you can leave all the default routes as is and just change the destroy action in your controller to try disable() instead of destroy().

Perhaps like this:

```
module MyDisableModule
  def self.included(recipient)
    recipient.class_eval do
    include ModelInstanceMethods
  end
end

  # Instance Methods
  module ModelInstanceMethods

    #Here is the disable()
    def disable
      if self.attributes.include?(:disabled)
        self.update_attributes(:disabled => true)
      else
        #return false if model does not have disabled attribute
        false
      end
    end
  end
end

#This is where your module is being included into ActiveRecord
if Object.const_defined?("ActiveRecord")
  ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, MyDisableModule)
end
```

And then in your controller:

```
def destroy
  @model = Model.find(params[:id])
  if @model.disable #instead of @model.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully disabled #{@model.name}."
    redirect_to #wherever
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Failed to disable #{@model.name}."
    render :action => :show
  end
end
```

Note that in this example, disabled is the attribute and disable is the method that makes a model disabled.

Comment: Wow, way above me.  First are these 2 different files or 1?  I ask because I see an extra end on ModelInstanceMethods. Imagine I can add it to my /lib dir and just call include on it/them?

Comment: No, it can all be put in the same file in lib, except for the destroy which as I said goes in your Controller. But if you feel it is to complicated or just want to try it out at frist, then you can take the disable method and manually put it in the model you want to try with first.

Comment: Trying, but doesn't seem to be working.  Added Lib file (exactly as posted above for testing) but keep getting Failed to disable?

Comment: Okay, it can be a bit tricky to troubleshoot sometimes, but I think the most common problem is that you forget to restart rails after you make modifications in the lib folder so just make sure that is not the problem. Then, if you find it difficult to locate the problem, take it one step at a time. Like I said, put the disable method into one specific model and try it out to make sure that at least works before you start looking for the cause why it is not getting included into ActiveRecord.